# representation of C++ by clang

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, clang, dwarf

I would like to know which classes clang uses to represent C++(not C) source information

I need the internal representation ,that can be useful in the DWARF(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) .For example for the type the relevant info could be :size in bytes of this type,byte alignment of this type etc

I have downloaded LLVM + Clang.
I have looked at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html but didn't found my answer so
could someone direct me maybe I missed something and tell  me in which classes I have to start looking for this data?

Comment: What do you mean by "source information"?

Comment: Do you mean the internal representation of your source code inside Clang?

Comment: Are you looking for the classes used to implement the parse tree or the abstract syntax tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should look at the [AST Library](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#libast) since the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) is used to represent parsed information. If you want to learn by example, the [Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) might be of interest for you, because it parses the C source and performs static code checks to find bugs.

Comment: I need representation for C++ (not C)

Comment: May be more precisely - I need the internal representation ,that can be useful in the DWARF.For example for the type the relevant info could be :size in bytes of this type,byte alignment of this type etc.

Comment: None-the-less, this answer will probably still be relevant, even if grundprinzip does not know that C and C++ are quite different languages. (Or, he may have misread the question - easy to do)

Comment: This info is in AST both for C and C++. E.g. Clang::Type has "Type::isClassType" which is true for C++ classes. The CXX is a prefix of pure C++ things.

Comment: @Yakov: size and alignment vary depending on the platform the code is generated for and is not an inner property of the class (for example, between a 32 bits and a 64 bits build, the size of the pointers vary). Still it should be possible to retrieve this from the AST.